# Scrolling the modal when the page scrolls

Tags: java, php, javascript, jquery, html

I am having one overlay in the page as this, Check the link.

[SLIDER DEMO](http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/slide/)

Once the page loads it will come in. Then when you scroll the page down the overlay remains the same.  It should also scroll up as the page scrolls upto some extent as mentioned in that URL.  Then again when user scroll back it should appear.
I am using this code for doing that,  `slideme()` brings the overlay in and `reset()` makes it to go back.

Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    SlideMe();

    $('body').keypress(function(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode == 27)
        {
            reset();
        }
 });

    });
    function SlideMe()
    {   
        if(document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value == 1)
        {
            document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value =0;
            reset();
            return false;
        }

        $lngDocWidth = ($(document).width()/3)+32;

        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
            $("#fb").animate({marginRight:$lngDocWidth}, 1500);         
        });

        $("#feedbackimg").css("margin-right", '100px');
        $("#feedbackimg").css("float", 'right');

        document.getElementById('hdnFBStats').value= 1;
    }

    function reset()
    {
        $("#fb").css('margin-right', '0px');
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
    }
```

Comment: I don't actually see a question?

Comment: If you goto this link http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/slide/ You can see a overlay coming in.  if you scroll the page the overlay remains the same as it is.  my question is, the overlay should also scroll up as the page scrolls.  Hope i am clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to modify your css.
 Just put style `position` as `absolute` instead of `fixed`.

```
#fb {
    position: absolute;
    right: -505px;
    top: 150px;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Edit: Hope this may help you.

```
 function thisfunc(evt) {
    if(window.pageYOffset>=400) { 
       // if(sent to right) { 
       //send to right 
       //}
    }
    else {
       // if(sent to middle) {
       //send to middle and restore
       //}
    }
    }
    document.onscroll=thisfunc;
```

Comment: Thankyou.  You answered my one of the question.  Its working fine.  The major thing is, if users scroll down to some extent it should come back to its position. i.e, middle right corner. then when users scroll up it should come back outside.

Comment: Hey Great man...!! Its working cool.  But when pages scroll fast it disturbs..

Comment: You have to prevent the execution of function on each function call. **see the edit**. But I wonder how the user see the restored box when the page scroll down to some extent.

Comment: No, There is a start now button at the left end of the box.  when it hides, it should come to middle  right corner of the browser.  so if user needs that overlay it should come again when user clicks start now button.